# Webフォントと文字エンコーディングの関係

Tags: font

ざっと気になったので質問です。

Webフォントは文字コード依存していないと聞きましたが、内部的にどのようにしているのでしょうか?
以下かなと推測していますが、詳しい文献が見つかりませんでした。
・ブラウザ側で文字コードをUTF8に解釈してから参照される
・フォントデータの中に、たとえばSJIS用の文字コードのインデックスも定義されている

詳しい方お教えください。

Comment: 「Webフォントは文字コード依存していない」とはどなたがどのような文脈で仰ったのでしょうか? 「Webフォント」で検索して引っかかったサイトをかたっぱしから探して見ましたが、そのような記述は見つけられませんでした。「環境非依存で意図したフォントを表示できる」と言う意味の話を聞き違えている可能性はありませんか? ちなみにブラウザがテキストを描画するときには、フォントを利用するために必要なコード変換は行ってくれます(最近のPCやMacに内臓されているフォントはUnicodeベースの内部形式になっているが、SJISのページも表示できます)から、Webフォントであろうと内臓フォントであろうと「文字コード依存していない」と言うことになります。

Comment: @OOPer ご意見には同意するのですが、「最近のPCやMa‌​cに内臓されているフォントはUnicod‌​eベースの内部形式になっている」というのは本当なのでしょうか？　フォントに詳しくないので OpenType フォントの仕様を読んでいるのですが、OpenType フォントは内部的にはそれぞれのグリフに GID と呼ばれる ID を割り振り、cmap と呼ばれるルックアップテーブルを使って文字コードからグリフへ変換していると理解しました。この理解が正しければ、Unicode ベースの内部形式とは違うように思います。 http://www.morisawa.co.jp/culture/dictionary/1921

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。確かに「Unicodeベースの内部形式」では、Unicode以外には対応できないように読めますね。「Unicode対応の内部形式で、最近のPCやMacに対応したフォントならUnicodeベースの対応表しか内蔵していない」とでも書いた方が良かったかもしれません。

Comment: 「Webフォントは文字コード依存していない」は立ち話でのことなので、文献は存在しないのですが、いただいたコメントから察するに、フォントそのものの仕様の話ですね。
まさに @nekketsuuu さんに掲載いただいたcmapの話ですね。ここでは以下のように書かれていることから、文字コードごとに定義があることになります。
「CMap・cmapは対応する文字コードの数だけエンコーディングテーブルを持ち、それぞれ「UniJIS-UTF8-H」「UniJIS-UTF16-V」というような名称が付けられています。」
つまりSJISに対応するcmapをもたないフォントの場合は、SJISのページは表示できないことになります。

以下が文字コードと文字の関連付けをあらわしていますね。
[エンコーディング | フォント用語集 | 文字の手帖 | 株式会社モリサワ](http://www.morisawa.co.jp/culture/dictionary/1902)

Comment: _つまりSJISに対応するcmapをもたないフォントの場合は、SJISのページは表示できないことになります_ 誤りです。引用されたページを誤解されているようです。(ちなみに後半の段落はcmapテーブルの話ではなく、テキストファイルの「エンコーディング」の話です。)先に書いたように文字コード変換はOS側で行いますので、SJISのページでもUnicodeベースのcmapテーブルしか持たないフォントで表示できます。また nekketsuu さんが引用されたページにしろあなたが引用されたページにしろ、OpenTypeやTrueTypeなど、ごく普通の内蔵フォントや市販フォントにも使われているフォント形式の話で、「Webフォント」に限った話ではありません。立ち話ということなので、「Webフォント」という言い方でフォントフォーマットの話をされていたということなのでしょうか?

Comment: 立ち話の段階ではフォント自体まで突っ込んだ話をしいてませんでした。WebフォントでHTMLのエンコーディングに関係するかどうかといった話です。なるほど、Webフォントの話からだったのでHTML側のエンコーディングと混同しましたが、OS内部で解釈するUnicodeの話ですね。これであればUnicodeのcmapで充分ということも理解できます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントでいただいている内容で答えが出たので、リライトしておきます。

### WebフォントはHTMLエンコードによって出ないものがあるのかどうか。

- WebフォントはOSのフォントと同じで、内部的にはUnicodeで格納されている。
- HTMLエンコードにかかわらず内部Unicodeで解釈されているので、表示時にはUnicodeのマッピングを基にフォントが表示される。
- 最近のフォントはUnicodeのマッピングしか持っていないので、内部コードがUnicode以外の
  OSの場合は、Webフォントなどの外部から取得するタイプのフォントを使用すると代替フォントになる。

Comment: 「Web フォントも OS のフォントと同じ」←この言い方には注意が必要だと思います。まず PC/Mac で使われるフォントは TrueType や OpenType だけではありません。用途によっては PostScript フォントなど、別形式のものが使われるでしょう。更に、Web フォントにもいくつか形式があるようです。特に TrueType/OpenType を拡張した [Web Open Font Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format) というものがあります。 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#File_formats

Comment: そうですね。確かにWOFFはOSフォントではないので、PostScriptフォントも含め調査のうえ文言変えます。

Comment: 最近のフォントと文字コード(正確を期すなら文字エンコーディングと言った方が良いかもしれません)の関係をうまく簡潔にまとめられていると思うのですが、3点目については『「豆腐□」になるのは、内部コードがUnicode以外のOSの場合に、Unicodeマッピングしか持っていない最近のフォントを表示している場合(だけ)』なんて誤解をする人が出そうなので、わかっている人には蛇足なのですが、少々の補足を。Unicode対応のOSでUnicodeマッピングを持っているフォントを表示しても、豆腐「□」になることはあります。これは「Unicodeのマッピングを持っている」かどうかと「Unicodeの全文字に対応するグリフを持っている」かどうかは全く別の問題だからです。従って、Unicodeとして有効なコードポイントを指定してUnicodeマッピングのフォントを使ってその文字を描画しようとしても、そのフォントがそのコードポイントの文字に対応するグリフを持っていなければ、豆腐になるか代替フォントで表示されるかのどちらかになります。「Webフォント」と言うのはまさにそれを解消する仕組みで、表示したいコードポイントに対応するグリフを持つWebフォントを使用することによって、必ず意図した字形を表示することができる、と言う訳です。

Comment: おっしゃるとおり。Webフォントの場合は豆腐にはなりえませんね。今回はWebフォントがメインの話題なので修正しました。